# Property/fields thread synchronization

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have read some stuff on ios sdk about multithreading, but I still didn't find the answer to the problem:
In the main thread I have a property, the program does some stuff in a thread, where the value of the property is changed, the other thread needs that changed value.
So how can I change the value of a property or a field in one thread, so that it would change for all threads?

Answer (score 3):

Changing a property on a single object changes the value "for all threads" basically. There's no thread-specific copies of objects unless you make them yourself.

For multithreaded programs, the major challenge is making sure two threads aren't trying to access/write the same memory (a property, in your case) at the same time.  Easiest way (but not necessarily most efficient, or fool-proof way) to do this for your property in question is to exclude the "nonatomic" attribute from your property declaration. 
(EDIT: this assumes you're using `@synthesize` to implement your properties, and not `@dynamic` nor have custom overriding getters or setters.)

Multi-threading is a bit of a large topic to cover here, but Apple's documentation is a good place to start for more info: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Wouldn't the easiest way be locks?

Comment: by not specifying "nonatomic" in your property declaration, the compiler puts lock code in, behind the scenes.  This is assuming you're `@synthesize`-ing them though. Edited answer to clarify this.

Comment: Yea, but I didn't include "nonatomic" attribute into the property declaration.Though, the value is changed only in one thread, but not in the main one or in the one I need.

Comment: May be I should post a question with my code attached to it
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10127700/property-value-in-multithread-program

Comment: @Alexander then something else is going on. Objects & properties do not have thread-specific values. Make sure you aren't accidentally using a copy or clone of the object.  If that isn't enough help, then you'll have to post your code.