# Property value in multithread program

Tags: objective-c, ios

I got two properties initialized in header file:

```
@property (readwrite, assign) int Figure1;
@property (readwrite, assign) int State;
```

and in .m

```
@synthesize Figure1;
@synthesize State;
```

Then I got

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = 
    [[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeLeftMade:)] autorelease];
    [swipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
```

and

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *oneFingerTwoTaps = 
    [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(ooneFingerTwoTaps)] autorelease];
    [oneFingerTwoTaps setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
    [oneFingerTwoTaps setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:oneFingerTwoTaps];
```

initialized in the class.

The methods called:

```
- (void)ooneFingerTwoTaps
{
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(oneFingerTwoTaps) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}

- (void)swipeLeftMade:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(moveLeftSwipe) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}
```

In the first thread there is the main program:

```
- (void)oneFingerTwoTaps
{
    PlayScene *tView = [[PlayScene alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 420)];
    [self addSubview:tView];
    while (GameState==GamePlaying) {
        Figure1 = 1; State = 1;
        [self moveFig];
    }
}
```

In the second thread I need to use the values of properties that are changed on the first thread

```
-(void)moveLeftSwipe  {
int fset = State, figure=Figure1;
//some other stuff
}
```

But the problem is that the value of properties isn't shared between threads, I was told that "nonatomic" might cause such problem, but I didn't use it. May be I am declaring something wrong?

Comment: Just a quick note: you should use `arc4random_uniform(7)` instead of the modulus method.

Comment: Have you set breakpoints to verify that the values are being set and that both selectors are being called when you expect them to?

Comment: Also: 
`[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(moveLeftTapped)...` vs `-(void)moveLeftSwipe...`  did you copy/paste the wrong code?

Comment: My bad, edited the code.
selectors are being called when I expect them to, what do you mean "to verify that the values are being set"?

Comment: They are assigned only in one thread on some reason

Comment: Problem solved, just used static variables instead of properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just used static variables instead of properties. Static variables are shared between threads.